# How can I run shell (terminal) in Google Colab?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, google-colaboratory

I know that I can call `!ls` to issue `ls` command to shell.

But I want features like history or tab-completion.

Is it possible to do so in Google Colab?

Comment: why is `!<cmd>` not sufficient for you?

Comment: I want features like history or tab-completion

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use jQuery Terminal Emulator backed with `google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction`

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QZywh4xiiR8BX14dThVVRaJ3c7hgJcyU).

The key part is here, where you back it with shell function.

```py
def shell(command):
  return JSON([getoutput(command)])
output.register_callback('shell', shell)
```

And here's how you use `invokeFunction`:

```js
try {
    let res = await google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('shell', [command])
    let out = res.data['application/json'][0]
    this.echo(new String(out))
} catch(e) {
    this.error(new String(e));
}
```

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

#### Update (7/2020)

I have taken @Anant's answer and add it into my library. Now you can run console easily with just

```
!pip install kora
from kora import console
console.start()  # and click link
```

#### Update (12/2020)

If you subscribe to Colab Pro, terminal is now available. Just click the 'Terminal' icon on the left pane.

[image: Terminal Icon]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where the terminal icon is located? Also, is this available only for Colab Pro users? Because I can't find it...

Comment: @gorjan I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Probably it's not available for everyone yet, I don't have it for example

Comment: I'm fairly sure that as of 20DEC2020, terminal is only available on the for-pay, US only Pro level of Colab. I'm using the free level and don't see a terminal window. 

![](https://i.imgur.com/E7tghNE.png)

Comment: Teleconsole (that's used by kora) is discontinued.

Comment: the Kora route is not working

Comment: the strategy shown in the example  notebook does generate a console, but I could not run mysql inside it. the next solution with xterm worked with mysql

Answer (score 39):

I just wrote a tool to run xterm in colab. Just three lines of code and you can get an interactive terminal.

```
!pip install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm
%xterm
```

- Notebook: [image: Open In Colab]
- Github: https://github.com/InfuseAI/colab-xterm
- Blog post: https://blog.infuseai.io/run-a-full-tty-terminal-in-google-colab-without-colab-pro-2759b9f8a74a

If you feel it is useful, please star this project. ⭐️

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: Man this thing is crazy, THANKS!!

Comment: Amazing. This is the best option for running Linux on an instance! If you use this, please star @popcorny 's repo so they get credit for this work:  https://github.com/InfuseAI/colab-xterm

Comment: It doesn't work anymore? The terminal fills up with endless 404 errors... too bad, it works nicely for about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 19):

Just type the following. It will spawn a bash session.

```
!bash
```

It displays commands in a password format. If you change the input type from `password` to `text` using browser dev tools, it will be really helpful.

Comment: This displays my commands in a password format, i.e. the characters are hidden.

Comment: using your browsers dev tools chenge type of input box from "password" to "text"

Answer (score 11):

### Google Colab Shell

**Free Terminals for everyone**
 Displays a terminal for Google Colab

https://github.com/singhsidhukuldeep/Google-Colab-Shell

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Setup

```sh
pip install google-colab-shell
```

### Usage

[image: https://colab.research.google.com/github/singhsidhukuldeep/Google-Colab-Shell/blob/master/Google_Colab_Shell.ipynb]

```py
# import the module once
from google_colab_shell import getshell
```

```py
## Anytime you want to open a terminal

getshell()

getshell(height=400) # custom height of the terminal
```

**IMPORTANT:** *Make sure `getshell` is the last command in the cell.*

### Documentation

```
Displays a terminal for Google Colab. <3 Google

Make sure this is the last command in the cell.

    Parameters
    ----------
    height : int, default 400
        height of the rendered terminal

    Returns
    -------
    IPython.display.HTML
        Displays the terminal

    Examples
    --------
    >>> getshell()

    >>> getshell(height=400)
```

[image: https://github.com/singhsidhukuldeep/Google-Colab-Shell]

Please Contribute: https://github.com/singhsidhukuldeep/Google-Colab-Shell#todo-want-to-contribute

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Better try this -

1. Install Teleconsole on Colab, its a package to use terminal over internet -

   ```
    !curl https://www.teleconsole.com/get.sh | sh
   ```
2. Run below code on colab notebook to use Teleconsole -

   ```
    import subprocess as sp
    process = sp.Popen("teleconsole",shell=True,stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
    for i in range(6):
      print(process.stdout.readline().decode())
   ```

   You should get output something like -

   ```
    Starting local SSH server on localhost...
    Requesting a disposable SSH proxy on eu.teleconsole.com for root...
    Checking status of the SSH tunnel...

    Your Teleconsole ID: eu88d75d24084905shgdjhjhfgd1934e55c3786438a3

    WebUI for this session: 
    https://eu.teleconsole.com/s/88d75d24084905shgdjhjhfgd1934e55c3786438a3
   ```
3. Either open the web interface by following the link for accessing the terminal or open a local shell terminal and install Teleconsole using the command -

   ```
    curl https://www.teleconsole.com/get.sh | sh
   ```

   Then use the below code to join the terminal using Teleconsole Id you got in step No. 2-

   ```
    teleconsole join <Teleconsole ID>
   ```

This method can also be tunneled through ssh with some additional steps.

Comment: process.stdout.readline().decode() should be p.stdout.readline().decode()

Comment: Teleconsole is shut down since April 9th, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

`!sh` should work, it doesn't takes commands in asterisk form as mentioned by some people here. Currently working fine as of **December 7, 2023**