# Running Train a GPT-2 (or GPT Neo) Text-Generating Model w/ GPU on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When I start "Running Train a GPT-2 (or GPT Neo) Text-Generating Model w/ GPU on Colab" in my Colab, following error comes up:

> ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement tensorboard~=2.5, but you'll
> have tensorboard 2.4.1 which is incompatible. ERROR: pytorch-lightning
> 1.3.8 has requirement PyYAML<=5.4.1,>=5.1, but you'll have pyyaml 3.13 which is incompatible.

What to do? Is it because of my Mac, or do I need to upgrade my Colab account would that help?

Comment: You'll need a version of tensor board >= 2.5. You have 2.4.1 so you need to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the default packages installed in the Colab environment. I does not depend on the platform you are using to access Colab or on the type of your subscription.

You have to upgrade the Python packages using `pip`.

In general you can run shell commands like `pip` in Colab prepending a `!` character,
so in your case the following lines should be sufficient to fix the problem

```
!pip install tensorboard==2.5
!pip install pyyaml==5.4.1
```

If you need to run more shell commands, you can use more user-friedly methods (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318692/how-can-i-run-shell-terminal-in-google-colab)).