# Running python commands in a terminal in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've uploaded a directory of codes in Google Colabs. I need to run python command lines in a terminal that I'm unable to open.

I tried each and every solution suggested in [How can I run shell (terminal) in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318692/how-can-i-run-shell-terminal-in-google-colab) but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide eg. a snapshot of your observed output or its error message? It helps in debugging your problem.

Comment: Sure. I do have the screenshots but don't know how to add them here in the comment line? Could you kindly guide me?

Comment: You can just paste the image here and it will be converted into a link. Alternatively, if you encountered problem doing so, you may upload to Imgur/GDrive and share the link here.

Comment: I just dragged the screenshot (png file) here but it opens up in a new tab.
Here's the link from my desktop file:///Users/solomon/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202022-02-01%20at%2012.22.31%20AM.png

Comment: That is not how it works. That is your local windows path, and is only accessible by yourself.  Can you refer to this link at time=7.16 to see how to upload an image? https://youtu.be/Vt-Wf7d0CFo?t=436

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The video is for uploading images while posting a question or an answer. Not in the comment section. Anyways I've edited the question and added the image. You'll notice files (output) being created in the 3envs folder. The output creation stalled after a while and only 1 more file could be created after 15 minutes. I terminated the session after that.

Comment: I am very sorry @sam. I need to learn to read better, I just saw your comment on posting images in the comment section, I answered your question wrongly. My apologies.

Comment: I have a suggestion, can you try to execute the code using the Colab's cell instead of a bash terminal? I have encountered problem like yours back in my Colab days, the process is slow. So my suggestion is to ```cd``` to my working directory or get the path to your ```sweep.py```, and run the whole ```python3 scripts/sweep.py --models= ... ...``` command directly on the Colab's cell. I will update a sample on my answer with image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated 20220202

Can you try to execute your python scripts using the exclamation mark `!` from Colab's cell directly?

I believe I encountered identical issue back in my Colab days, the process will hung or froze over some time, especially when I am dealing with GBs of datasets. So, ultimately I just ran using the exclamation mark directly from my Colab's cell to resolve the issue.

[image]

---

Have you tried this with the following syntax?

```
!pip install google-colab-shell
from google_colab_shell import getshell

getshell()
getshell(height=400)
```

I understood that you have tried the solution from another post, but just in case that you missed out the `!`, and ignored the warning message, and that exclamation mark was actually causing the shell not spawning.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It does open the terminal but while executing the code I've noticed that it runs for at max about 10 minutes before freezing. I've kept the Colab tab open throughout periodically checking the progress but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Sam, I will try out on my side, get back to you ASAP. Also, can you provide a snapshot of how it looks when it hung?

Comment: I am not seeing the issue on my side, it has been idle for approximately 30 minutes and is still working. Let me try to figure out another approach to open a terminal.

Comment: `su - otheruser` doesn't work